# Conditioning group effect on values post-treatment variable

Tags: regression, causality, bias

I'm relatively new to causal inference, so please be gentle.

[image]

I have the above DAG, which represents the following variables:

- G: exposure variable, two factors (control and treatment)
- S: Pre-treatment variable, Continuous
- PT: Post-treatment variable, Continuous
- Y: Outcome of interest, Continuous

Is there a way to estimate the contrast effect between the two factors of G across the values of PT using regression analysis? I ask this because my basic understanding of causal inference tells me that conditioning on PT would incur post-treatment bias on the estimate.

Cheers

Comment: I'm a bit curious: if $S$ is a pre-treatment variable, why does it not influence the treatment $G?$ Conditioning on $PT$ as-is would definitely bias your result: $PT$ is a mediator, so conditioning on it would close off the causal effect of $G$ on $Y$ that is mediated through $PT.$

Comment: Hey Adrian, good question! The assignment of subjects to G was randomised, so S could not influence it. I can see from the estimates that effect of S is independent of G too. 

And thanks for validating my suspicions regarding conditioning on PT, I can see from the estimates that they have bias, just not sure how to reduce it.

Comment: The way to reduce the bias is not to condition on $PT.$ If you're in a linear regression setting, you should *not* include $PT$ on the RHS. You should not stratify your analysis on $PT.$

Comment: Indeed, thanks again for giving me some credence about removing it. Is there any non-regression analysis setting that might provide an unbiased estimate?